# jQuery .on to apply to all intermediate nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

Given a document such as this:

```
<body><div class="a"><div class="b"><div class="c"></div></div></div></body>
```

(in the example everything is a div - but they could be anything)

I want to run a click event handler for the div which was clicked and all its parent's

i.e. if you click on `.c` I would expect the event to fire for `.c` then `.b` then `.a`
If you click on `.b` then the event should fire for `.b` then `.a`

N.B. in this instance I am using `$('body').on('click', function(event){...})`
using `$('div').click(function(event){...})` is not a practical option in my instance for reasons not relevant to the question.

I tried walking the dom tree from within the event handler which works but the event object contains the wrong offsets.

So my question really is - is there a built in way to have the event handler called with the above pattern.

Or failing that - is there a built in way to manipulate offsets the event object given a "from" and "to" element.
i.e. something like `AdjustOffsets(event, $target, $target.parent())`

Or failing that - what logic do I need in order to perform this manipulation by hand.

On the last case I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
if ($target.css('position') != 'static' && $target.css('position') != '')
    {
        event.clientX += $target.css('left');
        event.clientY += $target.css('top');
    }
    event.clientX += $target.css('borderLeftWidth');
    event.clientY += $target.css('borderTopWidth');
    event.clientX += $target.css('marginLeft');
    event.clientY += $target.css('marginTop');
    $target = $target.parent();
    event.clientX += $target.css('paddingLeft');
    event.clientY += $target.css('paddingTop');
```

This fails because the CSS properties contain units.
The units are easily stripped but I believe some browsers return the original unit here (which could be `em` or `pt` for example) whereas the `clientX` property is required to be pixels - so conversion is necessary.

Also it was a best-guess on my part and probably misses a thousand obscure css3 cases - hence my ambitious desire for some kind of built-in method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is. Do you want a click-event to trigger on for instance `div.a` when you click on `div.c`? If so. This should already happen, since click events by default bubble through the DOM.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLjcq/) and you'll see that if you'd click on `div.c`, the click events for `div.b` and `div.a` will be fired as well.

**edit:**
New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdpzE/2/), with just 1 `on()`

Comment: I want a single call to .on to handle all these events

Comment: ok so now this will only apply to div but I actually need it to apply to any type of element. Will changing this to * cause a massive slow down on a large document? (The document in question can be huge).

Hence why I applied it to body (mistake in my original question will be corrected momentarily)

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't use the wildcard. Of course I don't know what exactly you're building, but I can't imagine every single element on the page needs te be clickable.

Can't you make a list of clickable elements, or give all clickable elements a certain class. Because then you could do something like:

`$('div, a, p, section').on('click', function(){...` or `$('.clickable-class').on('click', function(){...`

Comment: hmm, the problem is the code in question is in a generic module and has no idea when it will be needed.
It is true that not every element is clickable but what is important here is that the parents of the element clicked are checked.
But thinking about it there is an attribute I can use in the selector so I suppose this does work

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive trigger within your event handler, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(e){

    // .. do stuff

    $(this).parent('.someClass').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: The above will cascade execute the event handlers for your given structure. By offsets I presume you mean pointer location? Why is this relevant? You haven't specified this in your question.

Comment: I have mentioned offsets extensively in my question!
clientX/Y
screenX/Y
offsetX/Y
pageX/Y